# How create a div that's position is fixed compatible with IE, FF & Chrome

Tags: css, fixed, css-position

I have fixed(position) on the left. It has style="overflow: auto" and then the rest of articles go to the right which is scrollable.

Some of options in the sidenav is not visible in IE and FF. I understand that Browser view port are different for different browsers. How can I adjust the height of sidenav so that all options are visible.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean to say the *bottom* portion of the div gets hidden because there is not enough viewport height available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

http://jsbin.com/ixula4

What I've done is that that I added `top: 0; height: 100%` to the fixed positioned div along with `overflow: auto`. Seems to work in FF, Chrome and IE7 (standards-compliance mode). Not sure about other browsers. You better research on "100% height divs" for hacks you can use in other browsers.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE6. There is no overflow on the left div (all the content is displayed), and it doesn't float either, the right div is displayed below (maybe just a width issue)

Comment: AFAIK, IE6 does now know what `position: static` is :(

Comment: @Thibault, You may need to tweak it a bit, but this technique can definitely work in IE6.  I don't have the code handy, but this may call for the old "hasLayout" hack.  Also, **position:static** is irrelevant since it's the default.

Comment: My bad, in my answer and above-mentioned comment I meant to say `position: fixed`. Nevertheless, there are articles that describe how you can "emulate" `position: fixed` in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow-y:auto` to the sidenav, this will make the sidenav content scrollable when the height of the viewport is lesser than that of the content in sidenav.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use overflow:visible instead of auto.

Also fixed is not supported on older IE only from IE7+.

Do you have an example page to look at?

Answer (score 0):

This article seems very helpful for you because their demo appears to be what you are trying to do. http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/floater_fixed.html Offers a cross-browser position:fixed solution.